# How to redirect to login when there is an error in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, angular, express

When the user receives error from backend i am trying to go back to login page . so my code goes as follows

**authServer.js**

```
app.use('/login', authService.login);

// other code ...

app.use(errorHandler);

function errorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err)
  }
  if(err.response){
  res.redirect("/login");
  }
  else {
  res.status(500)
  res.render('error', { error: err })
}
```

the error thrown by authService.login method reaches the error hander but redirection is not happening . i also tried res.redirect(config.get("loginUrl")) but it doesnt seem to work . in few question it was given to use window.location.href = config.get("loginUrl") but it throws error as window is not defined . As window is not supported  in nodejs. what is the right way to redirect to login Url . Login url will be something like external url "http://www.google.com"

**UPDATE**

As suggested tried by modifying as follows

```
function errorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
      if (res.headersSent) {
        return next(err)
      }
      if(err.response){
      return res.status(err.response.status).send({ message : err.response.message } )
     }
      else {
      res.status(500)
      res.render('error', { error: err })
    }
```

**Angular service**

```
getUser() {

this.http.post<User>(url , data).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = 'Unknown error!';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // Client-side errors
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // Server-side errors
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    window.alert(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

**user.ts**

```
getUsers() {

this.userService.getUser().subscribe(data=>{
            this.user= data
            },
             error => {
            console.log(error) ---> never printed
 }
            );
}
```

This is what i have tried but the error doesn't seem to be captured at all . This was the solution suggested in all questions. But the thing i could see the json only in response tab of network but never been caught as error and printed on console

Comment: Do it on the client-side.

Comment: I tried return res.status(error.response.status).send({ message : error.response.message}) but I am not getting it in catch of service .. in tool I could see the response . But somehow it is not getting caught by service at all.. that's why checking for options to redirect from node itself

Comment: This error handling is on the client's responsibility. Throw 401 and do the redirect on the client. Share some relevant client code, abd we'll try to help.

Comment: @noam steiner i have updated the code changes . would be helpful if you guide . how can i send the error response so that it can be captured in error of service